# Enable AES encryption on CC2650 over contiki

Tags: aes, contiki

How can I enable AES encryption on Contiki? I am using cc22650 Sensortag platform and MQTT to communicate with a broker.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Contiki AES is provided [here](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/core/lib/aes-128.c) in core/lib/. You can have a look at [CCM*](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/core/lib/ccm-star.c) for authenticated encryption as well. CCM* gives the facility to use only encryption or only authentication or both encryption and authentication.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I will have a look at it :)

Comment: @JuanMa: Was the answer helpful?

Comment: Yes yes. Sorry I have been disconnected these days and I forgot to accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @JuanMa note that this is software AES implementation, which might be quite slow. CC2650 does have HW accelerated AES128. We have a driver for that for Contiki, but it's not released for the public yet.

Comment: I do not need to be fast on my app but I need to consume as less as possible and CPU time means power. Is your driver going to released soon? Thanks for the answer :)